# Check how many users are using application on network?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a winform application on my network drive that many users are using. Is there a way to track how many users either by count or by their domain username who is using the application? I've look around and can't find any starting point on this subject. Any help is appreicated. Thanks.

EDIT:

So I decided on application load to save a text document with the domain username as filename and when the user exit application to delete the text document. Within the application i have a listbox that gets the text files in the directory and shows who is logged in. Easy and simply. The End.

Comment: The application could periodically send notifications to some central server indicating usage (machine name, user name, anything else you might find useful).  Then that central server would have the data you want, profiling usage based on the last time any given combination of data was sent.

Comment: Easy and Simple. Until someone's application crashes and leaves the document in place.

Comment: my assumption is that the application doesn't crash, and if it did, when log back on, it will save over the old document and delete when app closes. Maybe once in a while delete files in there that are older than 1 week of last modified to get rid of these kind of files. Doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation, you will be able to see how many users and which users have your winform application open.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725689%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

It's a starting point :)